# Access two models in one view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, rails-routing

**Background:** I'm trying to create a simple feed reader for which I'm using the [feedzirra](http://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra). I am developing in Rails 3.

This is probably pretty simple, but I'm trying to figure out how to access the contents of two related models from a single view. The model relationship is as follows:

Feed has_many Entries

Entry belongs_to Feed

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use rails 3's nested models.

here are a few links to help you

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1
- http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes
- http://github.com/alloy/complex-form-examples